# how can we link UITableview in tab bar controller?

Tags: iphone

i have coded in applicationdidfinishing method in appdelegate.m file.RtbfViewController,infoViewController are UItableviewcontrolleras.but when i click HOME tab,it does not show table.what i have to do? anyone can help?

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
RtbfViewController *rtbfViewController = [[RtbfViewController alloc]    
                                          initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
rtbfViewController.tabBarItem.title = @"HOME";
InfoViewController *infoViewController = [[InfoViewController alloc] 
                                          initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
infoViewController.tabBarItem.title = @"INFO";
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                    rtbfViewController,infoViewController,nil];
tabBarController.customizableViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil];

[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't put any data in the tables yet, you won't get much indication of the tables being present.  It's hard to tell if this is your problem or not without seeing the code for your subclasses `RtbfViewController` and `InfoViewController`.

Just in case this is your problem: You can add data to your tables by implementing [the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), and from there implementing at least the two required methods:

- `– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`
- `– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`

and this methods is used for grouped tables:

- `– numberOfSectionsInTableView:`

Also, don't forget to set the `dataSource` instance variable of your `UITableView` if needed.

In general, the [`TableViewSuite`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TableViewSuite/index.html) is a useful code example from Apple for learning about the `UITableView` related classes.